# Screen orientation not locking on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I'm new to expo go react native and bumped into a problem within screen-orientation. In my expo go react native project I have:

```
import * as ScreenOrientation from 'expo-screen-orientation';

export default app = () => {
  async function changeScreenOrientation() {
    await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE);
  }
  changeScreenOrientation();
  return(restofcode)
};
```

The function allows me to rotate the device, and switch orientation. However it wont exclude portrait orientation. Recently, before expo go updated its app, the orientation never switched to portrait.

Anybody else experiencing the same issue?

I have tried `react-native-screen-orientation` - returned: "Cannot find property of null"

I have tried expo-screen-orientation

Answer (score 1):

in app.json check if this line is present "orientation": "portrait", if it is remove it. Also there seems to be a bug for iOS specifically   for "expo-screen-orientation" and workaround seems to be to use ScreenOrientation.unlockAsync() before doing anything with ScreenOrientation.
Here is where it is being discussed https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/23368